# How can I escape braces in string to be fed to sub process

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

```
    import subprocess
    profile_val = 'ishan'
    cmd = 'instaloader --post-metadata-txt="{likes} likes, {comments} comments, {caption}" --login=blabla_id --fast-update' + ' ' + profile_val)
    subprocess.call(cmd.split())
```

It not escaping braces in {likes} and treats like as separate part command and fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your problem is that you're using `split()` to construct the list of arguments to the command to execute. You're also using quotes, which are shell syntax even though you're not invoking a shell.

Just use an array in the first place, so not to have to split:

```py
cmd = ('instaloader', '--post-metadata-txt={likes} likes, {comments} comments, {caption}', '--login=blabla_id', '--fast-update', profile_val)
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Stephane Chazelas gives the best solution but if you **have to** split shell-like command you can use shlex.

```py
import subprocess
import shlex
profile_val = 'ishan'
cmd = 'instaloader --post-metadata-txt="{likes} likes, {comments} comments, {caption}" --login=blabla_id --fast-update "' + profile_val + '"'
subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd))
```